# Will information saved in standardUserDefaults go away with app update?

Tags: ios

A newbie question - I'm using [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] to store user
specified preferences. While testing my app, I see that the stored preferences
disappears if I delete and re-install the app on my iphone. I'm wondering if same will
happen when an user installs a subsequent updated version of the app? Does re-installing
from xcode (without actually deleting the app from phone) simulate the *app update*
scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if rebuilding with Xcode simulates an update, but user defaults are preserved when actually updating an application. Your application will continue reading their current values as usual.